# How to solve the recursive complexity T(n) = T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+cn

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

When calculate the median, we know that if we break the input array into subgroups as five and solve it recursively, we will get O(n) complexity, but if we break the array into 3, it won't return the O(n) complexity.

Does any one know how to prove it?

Comment: Do you mean `T(n/3)` in the title?  Can you elaborate on the "we know"?  Because I don't.

Comment: Google this. There are lecture slides posted by various instructors that explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It' gonna be `nlg(n)` .
Try to draw it's recursion tree : The total cost of each level is equal to n, and the depth of this tree is `lg(n)` .
Note : Actually it's depth is between `log(n)` base 3 and `log(n)` base 3/2, but since the order of logarithms in all bases are same, we can just consider it as `lg(n)`.

Comment: The depth is actually between log(n) base 3 and log (2*n) base 3. There is no 3/2 in the picture.

Comment: T(n/3) => Log(n) base 3, T(n/(3/2)) => Log (n) base 3/2.
Also, with a little bit of math, you can prove that log (2*n) base 3 is same as Log (n) base 3/2.

Comment: Log (2*n) base 3 is log 2 base 3 + log n base 3. It is not the same as log n base (3/2). You're right about the first part though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the recurrence in the title is wrong, but I think the [Master Theorem](http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dbabcock/PastCourses/cs360/lecture/lecture05.html) for solving recurrences will be handy. You can show that going from one denominator to another puts you into a different case which goes from `O(n)` to something worse.

Comment: I don't think that Master theorem can be applied on this problem. In order to use master, equation should be in the form of T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n). Am I right ?

Comment: @Rsh yes. I assumed that the recurrence in the title is not the one the OP is trying to solve. I googled this just now and turns out that's the right recurrence, so you're right, the Master Theorem is useless.